# private static method access from public static

Tags: java

I have a question regarding static method access. I have a class within i have 4 static method. as shown in code:

```
package com.itrucking.util;

public class ZKUtil implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * 
 * @author Shekhar
 * @param _class
 * @param listbox
 * To make Listbox sorting enabled
 * @throws NoSuchMethodException 
 * @throws SecurityException 
 */
public static void setSortingEnabled(Class<?> _class, Listbox listbox){
    Map<Listheader, String> sortingPair = new HashMap<Listheader, String>();
    sortingPair = getMapForSorting(_class, listbox);
    if (!sortingPair.isEmpty()) {
        for (Map.Entry<Listheader, String> entry : sortingPair.entrySet()) {
            entry.getKey().setSortAscending(
                    new FieldComparator(entry.getValue(), true));
            entry.getKey().setSortDescending(
                    new FieldComparator(entry.getValue(), false));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @author Shekhar
 * @param _class
 * @param listbox
 * @return Map<Listheader, String>
 */
private static Map<Listheader, String> getMapForSorting(Class<?> _class,Listbox listbox) {
    List<Listheader> headerList = getListHeaderList(listbox);
    Map<Listheader, String> sortingPair = new HashMap<Listheader, String>();
    System.out.println(_class);
    Field[] fields = _class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        // System.out.println(f.getName()+":"+f.getType());
        for (Listheader lh : headerList) {
            if (f.getName().equals(getId(lh)))
                sortingPair.put(lh, f.getName());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sortingPair);
    return sortingPair;
}

private static String getId(Listheader listheader) {
    String listheaderId = null;
    if (listheader.getId().contains("_")) {
        listheaderId = listheader.getId().split("_")[1];
        // System.out.println("listheaderId->"+listheaderId);
    }
    return listheaderId;
}

/**
 * @author Shekhar
 * @param listbox
 * @return  List<Listheader>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static List<Listheader> getListHeaderList(Listbox listbox) {
    List<Listheader> headerList = new ArrayList<Listheader>();
    Listhead listhead = null;

    List<Component> listboxComponentList = listbox.getChildren();
    for (Component listboxComponent : listboxComponentList) {
        if (listboxComponent instanceof Listhead) {
            listhead = (Listhead) listboxComponent;
            break;
        }
    }
    List<Component> listOfComp = listhead.getChildren();
    if (listhead != null) {
        for (Component c : listOfComp) {
            if (c instanceof Listheader)
                headerList.add((Listheader) c);
        }
    }
    return headerList;
}
```

}

and i am calling setSortingEnabled() method from onLoadShipperDetailsListCtrl() from code bellow :

```
 package com.itrucking.webui.controller;


 public class ShipperDetailsListCtrl{

/**
 * @param e
 * @return void 
 */
public void onCreate$window_shipperDetailsList(Event e){
    onLoadShipperDetailsListCtrl();
}


/**
 * @return void
 */
public void onLoadShipperDetailsListCtrl(){
    System.out.println("onLoadShipperDetailsListCtrl called.");
    shipperList = shipperService.getShipperList();
    doRenderListboxShipperDetailsList(shipperList);
    ZKUtil.setSortingEnabled(ShipperMaster.class, listbox_shipperDetailsList);
}
```

}

so what i think if i am calling setSortingEnabled() method from other class so i kept is as public and other method's i kept as private but it's giving me error as :
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/itrucking/util/ZKUtil.getMapForSorting(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/zkoss/zul/Listbox;)Ljava/util/Map;

Why there is error NoSuchMethodError for ZKUtil.getMapForSorting() call in setSortingEnabled()

I know we can call private method from public in the same class. So i am not able to understand what is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are sure that in ZKUtil you use a listbox imported from org/zkoss/zul/Listbox ?

Comment: yes Julien i am sure in fact i have confirmed that after your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `NoSuchMethodError` (the runtime error saying a method can't be found, instead of a compiler error) usually means that the `.class` files you're using are of a different version than the files you compiled against. In this case, you probably made changes to `ZKUtil.java`, but the JVM is loading an outdated version of `ZKUtil.class`. Clean and rebuild all of your `.class` files.

Comment: yeah..!! your right chrylis problem with loading class. Its working properly after clean and rebuild .

Thank you.